# DataContext Doesn't Exist in Dynamic Data Project?

Tags: sql, linq, dynamic-data, datacontext

This is really annoying...and I know it is something extremely simple...
1. I create a new Dynamic Data project.
2. I add a LINQ-to-SQL class and drag and drop some tables onto the class.
3. I open the global.asax.vb and uncomment the line: 
`DefaultModel.RegisterContext(GetType(YourDataContext), New ContextConfiguration() With {.ScaffoldAllTables = True})`
I remove YourDataContext and replace it with the DataContext from my LINQ-to-SQL class:
`DefaultModel.RegisterContext(GetType(NorthwindDataContext), New ContextConfiguration() With {.ScaffoldAllTables = True})`
I then try to debug/build/etc. and receive the following error:
Type 'NorthwindDataContext' is not defined
Why is it not defined? It seems like its not recognizing I created the DBML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange issue and I am still not sure that I have entirely fixed the issue. But, here is what I think I have learned:
1. If you are creating a New Project in VS2010 you must place the LINQ-to-SQL DBML file in the root project directory.
2. If you are creating a new Web Site in VS2010 you must place the LINQ-to-SQL DBML file in a newly created App_Code directory.
3. If you place it in the wrong place, scrap the project and start over - it doesn't seem to work even if you move the files to the correct location or recreate them in the correct location.
Dave.

Comment: Your #1 is what tripped me up also.  I though initially it was because I was using VS2012 (not the issue) or that the namespace was wrong (myprojectnamespace.app_code)  but changing the namespace didnt' fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Does your project compile? I am guessing you are missing the namespace to your data context. Something like this:

```
model.RegisterContext(typeof(MyApp.MyNamespace.NorthwindDataContext), 
new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

Comment: See, that is the issue. I have a line like that: 
DefaultModel.RegisterContext(GetType(phonesDataContext), New ContextConfiguration() With {.ScaffoldAllTables = True})
But...that gives an error...but I know the data context exists!

Comment: Did you add the *namespace* to your datacontext? MyApp.MyNamespace.NorthwindDataContext